# Filtering Object Array that has an array field Using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I have 2 data sets:

People:

```
[
    {id:1, selected:[1,2,3,4]},
    {id:2, selected:[1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id:3, selected:[11]},
    {id:4, selected:[1,2,5]}
]
```

selectedArray:

```
[1,2,3]
```

I can filter `People.id` by `selectedArray`:

```
_(People).indexBy('id').at(selectedArray).value();
```

But I'm stumped on how I would filter for a field that is not represented as a single value. eg. `People[0].selected` which is an array of integers.

Is it possible to only show `People` objects that contain at least 1 integer in the People selected field from `selectedArray`?

I tried this:

```
_.intersection(selectedArray, _.map(People, 'selected'));
```

I eventually want to have a `People` object array with a selected field which is limited to the integers of `selectArray`. So the result would be:

```
[
    {id:1, selected:[1,2,3]},
    {id:2, selected:[1,2,3]},
    {id:4, selected:[1,2]}
]
```

I'm currently going through a for loop to calculate this but I don't think it's a very good solution and I'm wondering if there's a more elegant approach than traversing through the entire object array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Array.some inside the filter (vanilla js):

```js
var sel = [1,2,3]

var arr = [
    {id:1, selected:[1,2,3,4]},
    {id:2, selected:[1,2,3,4,5]},
    {id:3, selected:[11]},
    {id:4, selected:[1,2,5]}
]

var res = arr.filter(x => x.selected.some(y => sel.some(z => z === y))).
map(x => {
 x.selected = x.selected.filter(y => sel.some(z => z === y));
 return x;
})

console.log(res)
```

or in lodash

```js
var sel = [1,2,3]

var arr = [
     {id:1, selected:[1,2,3,4]},
     {id:2, selected:[1,2,3,4,5]},
     {id:3, selected:[11]},
     {id:4, selected:[1,2,5]}
]
var res = _.filter(arr, x => _.some(x.selected, y => _.some(sel, z => z == y)))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. From this result, is there a way to filter through each selected property and limit it to the values from sel? So instead of getting {"id":2, "selected":[1,2,3,4,5]} i would get {"id":1, "selected":[1,2,3]}. Currently everything I'm doing is traversing and I'm seeing that lodash is a really good solution to simplifying code. Thanks!

Comment: you can map the output and filter the selected array, I added an example in the first case

Comment: I have a bit of learning to do but the answer is very clear, thanks again!